# Is Strickland's candy based on a real candy?

Tags: realism, the-shape-of-water

In the movie *The Shape of Water*, the government agent Strickland has a favorite type of candy that he often chews. He mentioned that the candy is cheap and common.

Is that candy based on actual candy in reality?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrvZ01dOIZI

Comment: @BCdotWEB oh so it's designed specifically for the movie?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Nice find and seems pretty definitive. Why not put it up?

Comment: BTW description about the candy starts at 3:00 in @BCdotWEB 's youtube link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a throwaway remark in this interview with Michael Shannon and Michael Stuhlbarg by SYFY WIRE, the candy was specifically designed for the movie. Its color was described explicitly in the script.

The interview touches on the subject from about 3:00: